# Calculate a triangle based on one angle and the lengths on either side of the perpendicular

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Considering a standard triangle as shown here:

[image]

*h* is perpendicular to *c*.

I know the lengths p and q, and angle C. It seems to me like that should completely define the triangle. The trouble is I cannot come up with the formulas to calculate the other lengths and angles.

The best solution I came up with so far is an iterative process:
c = p + q
Split angle C in C1 = C * p / c and C2 = C * q / c
Next, calculate: p / tan C1 - q / tan C2
If that is positive, add a small amount to C1 and subtract the same amount from C2. If negative, do the opposite.
Repeat the calculation and reduce the amount applied to the angles until I get "close enough".

But I expect there should be a more direct approach.

A simple example: q = 80, p = 45, and C = 90 degrees (π/2 rad).
Another example: q = 45, p = 32, and C = 64.9423845817 degrees (1.133458435047 rad).

Note: I initially asked this question on stackoverflow.com, but was told that math.stackexchange.com would be a better place for such questions.

Comment: One approach that may help (assuming the angle at $C$ is always $\frac {\pi}2$) is that this triangle has $c$ as a diameter of a circle with $C$ on its edge.

Comment: Also note that if $h$ is perpendicular to $c$ (with $\frac {\pi}2$ angle at $C$) you have three similar triangles here, so you can directly take ratios of the side lengths to get the various values shown.  For example, $\frac ca=\frac aq$.

Comment: Unfortunately angle C is usually not π/2. That was just for the simple example I came up with to get a nice solution.

Comment: Is $h$ at least perpendicular to $c$?  Otherwise, there's really not much that can be done...

Comment: Yes it is. I mentioned that in the subject of the question. For clarity I will also add it to the body of the question.

Comment: By the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), $C$ is on an arc of a particular circle. You can find it by building an *isosceles* triangle with the same base $c$ and same angle $C$; the circle is the circumcircle of that isosceles triangle. (When $C$ is a right angle, that circumcircle has $c$ for its diameter. So, this is a generalization of the suggestions made in other comments.) Then $p$ and $q$ tell you where to raise a perpendicular to the base; wherever that perpendicular meets the circle is your point $C$. ... Does that help?

Comment: Use the [Pythagoras' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and the [Law of Cosines](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html) to get (where $\gamma$ is the angle at C):
$$
a^2-b^2=q^2-p^2\\
a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\gamma)=(q+p)^2
$$
Which is a system of $2$ equations with $2$ variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a closed formula for the remaining sides:

$$\begin{align}
a&=\sqrt{q^2+h^2}\\
b&=\sqrt{p^2+h^2}
\end{align}$$

Where $h$ is calculated using $r$, in the following way:

$$\begin{align}
r&=\frac{q+p}{2\sin(\gamma)}\\
h&=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{q-p}{2}\right)^2}\mp\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{q+p}{2}\right)^2}
\end{align}$$

Where $\gamma\in(0,\pi)$ is the angle at point $C$, and "$\mp$" is resolved as:

$$
\mp=\begin{cases}-,& \text{if }\gamma\ge \pi/2\\+,& \text{if }\gamma\le \pi/2\end{cases}
$$

To see how we can obtain this, read the rest of the answer.

---

*I solved this using the "Inscribed Angle Theorem" mentioned in the comments.*

[image]

We first observe a triangle with sides $r,q+p,r$ and angle $2\gamma$ above $q+p$.

The [Law of Cosines](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html) gives fruit (where $q+p=c$):

$$
r=\frac{q+p}{\sqrt{2-2\cos(2\gamma)}}=\frac{c}{2\sin(\gamma)}
$$

WLOG the point above $q+p$ is $C'=(0,0)$.

Consider a circle with radius $r$ centered at $C'$, which will be given by $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

To get coordinates of $C$, we use [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)  linked [by Blue in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700873/calculate-a-triangle-based-on-one-angle-and-the-lengths-on-either-side-of-the-pe#comment7606045_3700873).

Your point $C=(\frac{q-p}{2},y_c)$ is then the intersection of the circle and the line $x=\frac{q-p}{2}$.

$$
y_c= \pm\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{q-p}{2}\right)^2}
$$

WLOG assume the positive solution (that $C$ is above $C'$), hence $\pm\to+$.

The height of $B,A$ points is given by [Pythagoras' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) on the $C'AB$ triangle.

$$
y_b=y_a=\pm\sqrt{r^2-\frac{c^2}{4}}
$$

Because of our assumption for $y_c$, here for $y_b=y_a$ the $\pm$ will depend on the $\gamma$. That is, if $2\gamma\ge\pi$ then $C'$ is below $\overline{AB}$, and else if $2\gamma\le\pi$ then $C'$ will be above $\overline{AB}$.

Their $x$-coordinates are simply $x_b=x_c-q$ and $x_a=x_c+p$.

Now we can get the sides $a,b$ as distances $a=d(C,B)$ and $b=d(C,A)$.

$$
a=\sqrt{(x_c-x_b)^2+(y_c-y_b)^2}\\
b=\sqrt{(x_c-x_a)^2+(y_c-y_a)^2}
$$

And we have all sides of the triangle now.

Comment: It took a while for me (not a mathematician) to understand the process, but thanks to your clear explanation I now believe I do.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

An alternative way using the identity

\begin{align}
\cot(\gamma_1+\gamma_2) 
&= 
\frac{\cot\gamma_1\cot\gamma_2-1}{\cot\gamma_1+\cot\gamma_2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Let $|AB|=c=p+q$,
$|CD|=h$,
$\angle BCA=\gamma$,
$\angle DCA=\gamma_1$,
$\angle BCD=\gamma_2$.

\begin{align}
\triangle ADC:\quad
\cot\gamma_1&=\frac{h}{q}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\triangle BCD:\quad
\cot\gamma_2&=\frac{h}{p}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Using \eqref{1}, we have

\begin{align}
\cot\gamma 
&= 
\frac{\cot\gamma_1\cot\gamma_2-1}{\cot\gamma_1+\cot\gamma_2}
=
\frac{\tfrac{h^2}{pq}-1}{\tfrac hp+\tfrac hq}
=\frac{h^2-pq}{(p+q)h}
=\frac{h^2-pq}{c\,h}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

\eqref{4} is equivalent to the quadratic equation in $h$:

\begin{align}
h^2-c\,\cot(\gamma)\,h-pq&=0
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

with two solutions

\begin{align}
h_1
&=
\tfrac12\,c\,\cot(\gamma)
+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{c^2\,\cot^2(\gamma)+4pq}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
h_2
&=
\tfrac12\,c\,\cot(\gamma)
-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{c^2\,\cot^2(\gamma)+4pq}
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

Note that 
$|c\,\cot(\gamma)|<\sqrt{c^2\,\cot^2(\gamma)+4pq}$,
so the expression \eqref{7}
would be negative
in both cases,
whether $\gamma$ is obtuse or acute,
that is, 
whether $\cot\gamma$ is positive or negative,
the expression \eqref{7} would be always negative,
and the expression \eqref{6} positive, so the only suitable (positive) 
solution is 
\begin{align}
h
&=
\tfrac12\,c\,\cot(\gamma)
+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{c^2\,\cot^2(\gamma)+4pq}
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

[image]

\begin{align} 
|AB|=c&=p+q
,\\
\end{align}

By the sine rule,

\begin{align}
R&=\frac c{2\sin\gamma}
.
\end{align}

Let $|CE|=h$. Then

\begin{align}
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac12ch
,\\
S_{ABC}&=\tfrac12\cdot|AC|\cdot|BC|\sin\gamma
\end{align}

$|AC|$ and $|BC|$ in terms of $h$:

\begin{align}
|AC|&=\sqrt{q^2+h^2}
,\\
|BC|&=\sqrt{p^2+h^2}
,
\end{align}

and we have

\begin{align}
c^2h^2&=(p^2+h^2)(q^2+h^2)\sin^2\gamma
,
\end{align}

which results in
\begin{align}
h^2&=
\tfrac12\,(c^2\,\cot^2\gamma+2pq)
\pm\sqrt{\tfrac14\,(c^2\,\cot^2\gamma+2pq)^2-p^2q^2}
.
\end{align}

***Edit***

Actually, the last expression can be simplified further,
and we have a neat single expression for $h$
\begin{align}
h&=
\tfrac12\,c\,\cot\gamma
+\tfrac12\,\sqrt{c^2\cot^2\gamma+4pq}
,
\end{align}
which automatically handles acute/obtuse angle $\gamma$,
so the two other side lengths are simply

\begin{align}
a&=c\sqrt{\frac pc
+\tfrac12\cot\gamma\,
\left(\cot\gamma+\sqrt{\cot^2\gamma+4\,\frac {pq}{c^2}}
\right)}
,\\
b&=c\sqrt{\frac qc
+\tfrac12\cot\gamma\,
\left(\cot\gamma+\sqrt{\cot^2\gamma+4\,\frac {pq}{c^2}}
\right)}
.
\end{align}

Comment: This produces the correct result, but how you converted the $c^2h^2$ equation in the last step to the $h^2$ equation is magic to me.

Comment: @Schelte Bron: Just let $h^2=x$ and solve a quadratic equation
plus some basic trig identities. Also use $c=p+q$ to simplify.

Comment: @Schelte Bron:  check out the simplified result.